# How does Relay cursor pagination handle big datasets when it always fetches the whole dataset?

Tags: database, postgresql, graphql, database-cursor

I am currently working on a GraphQL project that is using Apollo Server / PostgresQL and Knex/Objection.

The datasets I am working with could very easily go upwards to 100k items.

So the question for pagination came up and I was trying to find a way to work with cursor based pagination since it seems to be the standard these days.

But after checking out several implementations, such as:

https://facebook.github.io/relay/graphql/connections.htm#sec-Pagination-algorithm
https://github.com/Terminal-Systems/apollo-cursor-pagination

I got the feeling that for all these implementations, before slicing based on the cursor, the whole dataset is fetched. Which got me confused because that seems like a huge performance issue when you're working with bigger datasets?

Even in the Relay spec that I linked, it states that you start with `allEdges` before slicing depending on the before or after arguments.

Is there something that I am missing? Because I don't see how this could be a better approach then offset based pagination but I would love to be proven wrong and shown where my reasoning is off.

Cheers and happy Friday!

Answer (score 1):

The Relay spec does specify fetching all edges that satisfy the provided `before` and `after` argument and then slicing the data according to the `first` or `last` argument. And doing that can indeed be noticeably slower and more memory-intensive when working with larger tables.

The main benefit of using cursor-based pagination over offset-based is that it works better with tables where rows are frequently added or deleted. It's possible for an edge to be added or deleted while paginating -- this can result in either skipping edges or getting duplicate ones when using offset-based pagination.

Cursor-based pagination *can* be implemented in such a way that it doesn't require all rows to be fetched. There's libraries like [this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/objection-cursor) that do that. I can't speak to whether or not doing so would technically make your server not "up to spec", but I imagine as long as the result is the same, your server would still be compliant with Relay clients. That said, if you're not worried about supporting Relay clients on the front end, it's not necessary to implement Relay-style connections or any other part of the Relay spec. You can have cursor-based pagination outside of a Relay-compliant server.